# How to use conditional if statement in flutter for ontap ()

Tags: flutter

How do i use conditional ontap() on flutter, when i press the button the app checks if im singed in then if not it goes to the other function.

```
                onTap: () if (appStore.isLoggedIn) {
                  async {
                    await userService.getUser(
                        email: widget.providerData.email.validate()).then((
                        value) {
                      widget.providerData.uid = value.uid;
                    }).catchError((e) {
                      log(e.toString());
                    });
                    UserChatScreen(receiverUser: widget.providerData).launch(
                        context);
                    }
                  else {
                  SignInScreen().launch(context);
                  }
                  },
              ).expand(),
```

Comment: onTap should be given function. So, Put all the logic (do this when logged in and this when not logged in) there and it will work just fine.
[onTap docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector/onTap.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
onTap: () {
  if(conditions) {
    ...
  }
},
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?